# How to test DOM update in Vue.js with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I'm struggling to understand some basic concepts of unit testing in Vue.js using Karma, Mocha and Chai.

This is my component:

**`VueExample.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ name }}</p>
        <input v-model="name">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'VueExample',
        data () {
            return {
                name: 'Bruce Lee'
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is how I'm trying to test it:

**`VueExample.spec.js`**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueExample from "../../../components/VueExample";

describe('VueExample.vue', () => {
    let vm;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const Constructor = Vue.extend(VueExample);
        vm = new Constructor().$mount();
    });

    it('should change the name', done => {
        const input = vm.$el.querySelector('input');
        input.value = 'Chuck Norris';
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('p').textContent).to.equal('Bruce Lee');
        Vue.nextTick(() =>{
            expect(vm.$el.querySelector('p').textContent).to.equal('Chuck Norris');
            console.log(vm.$el.querySelector('p').textContent);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I use Karma to run the tests and Chai as assertion library. Everything is properly configured in `karma.conf.js`. When I run this test, it fails. The text inside the tag `<p>` doesn't change. The `console.log` command outputs *Bruce Lee*.

The tests are run with Firefox.

Comment: `v-model` [relies on the `input` event](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components), which does not occur simply by editing the input's value in JavaScript (this is true [outside of Vue](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XWJLVvE)). Dispatching the `input` event manually in your test should work. In your example, do `input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` after setting `input.value`.

Comment: @tony19 Thank you very much for the comment. I'd highly appreciate if you can resubmit it as answer.

Comment: No problem. I've submitted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-model` [relies on the input event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components), which does not occur simply by editing the input's value in JavaScript. This is true outside of Vue, as seen below:

```js
function logInput(e) {
  console.log('input', e.target.value)
}

function update() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#input1')
  input.value = "foo"
}
```

```html
<input oninput="logInput(event)" id="input1">
<button onclick="update()">Update textbox</button>
<div>Clicking button changes text but does not emit <code>input</code> event. See console.</div>
```

Dispatching the input event manually in your test should work. In your example, do `input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` after setting `input.value`:

```js
const input = vm.$el.querySelector('input');
input.value = 'Chuck Norris';
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); // input event required to update v-model
```

Comment: Thank you! Succinct and very clear answer. The link to the official documentation helped a lot too. It helps to really understand what's going on in the code example.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of input don't trigger Vue to update the model (Because input's properties aren't reactive).'

You can try it in your browser. Run in the console `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'Chuck Norris'` And nothing happens, the text of the `p` element is still "Bruce Lee".

The way to trigger Vue is by `input` event. so you should dispatch an `input` event. this can be someting like this:

```
let event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents')
event.initEvent('input', true, true)
vm.$el.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(event)
```

Comment: I'm still in the dark. I get the idea about the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), but where and how do I change the model value?

Comment: Please try vue-test-utils. It will be much simplier to test such scenarios.

Comment: cezar, it's as @tony19 shows - set the value then dispatch the event. If you use vue-test-utils, the equivalent is `.trigger()` but I'm not sure if it fits with Karma and Mocha so I'd stick with `input.dispatchEvent()` which is native and compatible with any testing framework.

Comment: @Shalom Peles Your answer points right where the problem is and which approach should be taken. However the code example isn't so good and uses the deprecated method `initEvent`. Therefore I just upvoted this one, and gave the bounty to the other answer, which is more elaborate.

Comment: @Anatoly Thanks, very probably I'll take advantage of vue-test-utils in the future. For now I needed to learn about this issue using Karma and Mocha.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the comments @Anatoly suggested to use the [Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/). I was playing around and came up with a solution I'd like to share:

```
yarn add -D @vue/test-utils
```

or:

```
npm install --save-dev @vue/test-utils
```

Then the test file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VueExample from "../../../components/VueExample";

describe('VueExample.vue', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(VueExample);
  });

  it('should change the name', done => {
    const textInput = wrapper.find('input');
    textInput.setValue('Chuck Norris');
    textInput.trigger('input');
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.equal('Bruce Lee');
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.equal('Chuck Norris');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

There is only one test in this example, but I still use `beforeEach` to make it easier expandable with further tests. Here we mount the Vue component `VueExample`. In the test we find the `<input>` tag, set its value to *Chuck Norris* and trigger the `input` event. We can see that the text node of the `<p>` tag is unchanged and still says *Bruce Lee*. This is due to asynchronous nature of the DOM updates in Vue.

Using `nextTick()` we can check that the chane has taken effect and the text node of the `<p>` tag equals to the previous set value, which is *Chuck Norris*.